# AngularJS - $q undefined in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I'm trying to inject **$q** into my directive, but though **$q** is defined as a *resolver()* at first, when calling the function it is undefined. Maybe something related to binding? I don't know.

```
(function () {
'use strict';
  myForm.$inject = ["$q"];
  angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('myForm', myForm);

  function myForm($q) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        ngSubmitFunction: '&',
      },
      templateUrl: 'myTemplate',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      controller: ["$scope", "$window", "$q", function ($scope, $window, $q) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.name = 'myForm';

        $scope.submitPromise = function(){};
        vm.ngSubmit = ngSubmit;
        function ngSubmit($form) {
          vm.submitDisabled = true;
          $form.$setSubmitted();
          if ($form.$valid) {
            $scope.submitPromise().then(function() {
                vm.submitDisabled = false;
            });
          }
        }
      }],
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log($q);
        scope.submitPromise = function($q) {
            console.log($q);
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            scope.ngSubmitFunction();
            return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
    };
  }
}());
```

The objective is to call *ngSubmit* when user clicks on a button. *ngSubmit* disables the button, waits for the async calls to be over and then enables the button.

In the example code, the 1st **console.log($q)** (executed when loading the page) outputs this:

> Q(resolver) {
>       if (!isFunction(resolver)) {
>         throw $qMinErr('norslvr', "Expected resolverFn, got '{0}'", resolver);
>       }...

Which to me looks like correct.
But when calling **submitPromise()** after pressing the button, this is the output:

> undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined

When is **$q** lost?

*Note:* this is not the only version I tried, originally all code was on controller, nothing on link. I've also been told this pattern is deprecated and to use this one, which is better:

```
function submitPromise($q) {
  return $q(function (resolve) {
    $scope.ngSubmitFunction();
  })
}
```

Nothing worked. Everything produces the same error, $q gets undefined at some point and can't find out why.

Answer (score 2):

Using `$q` as an argument parameter is causing `$q` to become undefined.

```
  myForm.$inject = ["$q"];
  angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('myForm', myForm);

  function myForm($q) {
    return {
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log($q);
        //scope.submitPromise = function($q) {
        //Remove $q as parameter
        scope.submitPromise = function() {
            console.log($q);
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            //scope.ngSubmitFunction();
            deffered.resolve(scope.ngSubmitFunction());
            return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
```

The `myForm` function is a directive construction function to which the AngularJS framework will inject service providers. But the `submitPromise` function is not injectable; it is a child function of `myForm`. All injections should be done in the parent function.

---

Also the code can be simplified by using `$q.when` to create a promise.

```
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    console.log($q);
    //scope.submitPromise = function($q) {
    //Remove $q as parameter
    scope.submitPromise = function() {
        console.log($q);
        return $q.when(scope.ngSubmitFunction());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not passing $q as arg fixed it, thanks! Now $q resolves as promise but still something doesn't work. Button is disabled, async function called and working fine. But **.then** is never called and the button never enabled again (though no output errors). I've also tried **$q.when** as you stated and this provokes a _"Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"_ (as if submitPromise went undefined). Which is funny, because submitPromise is called (therebefore, not undefined), console.log($q) outputs as a resolver, async functions are called, and then this error happens. Gotta love directives.

Answer (score 1):

You should solve with this different injection

```
(function () {
'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('myForm', ['$q', function($q){

      return {
        . . .
      }

  }]);
```

Hope I've been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The right code is ( I removed parameter from function declaration ):

```
$scope.submitPromise=function() {

  return $q(function (resolve) {//$q is available in function declared in the same scope
    $scope.ngSubmitFunction();
  });

}
```

Above code use `$q` variable from scope ( javascript scope not angular $scope ), `$q` is visible for all functions declared inside **myForm function**.

Your previous code used function parameter not `$q` from scope, parameter was not passed, so was **undefined**.

Javascript scope means everything between open tag **{** and close tag **}**. Check this example:

```
function(y){//scope start

  var x; //scope local variable

  var someFunc=function(){

   //here is available y and x variables

  };

  //scope end
}

//outside of scope - here variables x and y not exists
```